"release": "previous" 61.0 ERROR: Warning: (1) Unable to parse package2-descriptor.json: invalid attribute 'subscriberPackageId' at line 1, column 565
I am creating a multi dependant 2nd Gen Package, the project creation seems to be using salesforces most recent version, 61.0. Although, I need it to be the previous version, 60.0. So in my project-scratch-dev.json file, I added the attribute, "release": "previous". When I create the package, a new error arises,
Warning: (1) Unable to parse package2-descriptor.json: invalid attribute 'subscriberPackageId' at line 1, column 565
I am using the most up to date cli -
sf version
@salesforce/cli/2.44.8
Current status: Error
Package creation finished with status: Error. Here is the full report:
» Warning: Plugin @salesforce/plugin-packaging (1.19.0) differs from the version specified by sf (2.4.5)
(node:20092) Warning: org-api-version configuration overridden at 60.0
(Use node --trace-warnings ... to show where the warning was created)
Warning: org-api-version configuration overridden at 60.0
Warning: (1) Unable to parse package2-descriptor.json: invalid attribute 'subscriberPackageId' at line 1, column 565
=== Package Version Create Request
